# Windows GUI builder for iPhone/Android?

Tags: user-interface, build

I don't have a smartphone and need to build mockups for an application to explain the idea I have.

Is there a good GUI builder for Windows so I can build realistic mockups that look like screenshots of an application running on an iPhone or Androphone?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say whether or not you want your mocks to be live, but you do say "screenshots" and not "demos," so I presume not. In that case, what about Visio? You could grab a set of iPhone stencils (such as [the one in this article](http://willhacker.net/2011/09/17/iphone-stencils-for-visio/)) and away you go.